# Help identifying this short, red antenna-like(?) structure

Tags: identification

I saw this device along a trail while hiking in hills in the suburbs of Taipei. It sits on short legs only about 1.5 meters tall.

It has two attachments which appear to be thick cables but I couldn't tell for sure, the area is overgrown and behind a bit of a fence. These are the best zoomed photos I could get.

The exposed red cylindrical section in the middle appears to be made from some kind of dielectric insulator or maybe fiberglass, and I estimate it to be about 38cm (15 inches) long and about 10 cm (4 inches) in diameter.

If it were a base-loaded antenna I'd expect at least a little more radiator on top, and one coax instead of two cables. I don't think it's a red light either, it doesn't appear to me to be even partially translucent.

I've cropped the best view of the label. I can make out [ingelva parafulmini](http://www.ingelva.it/) and [Varese Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varese). The The part number is very difficult to read, and I've obscured the four digit serial number for a bit to anonymize the end-user. I don't know what this is nor whose it is, but it sets only about 2 meters off of a popular hiking trail and so it's at least not "top secret".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Spares: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckMF.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgRqP.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Lightning prevention system](http://www.ingelva.it/index.php?pid=102&lang=E&ncol=1) made by Italian firm INGELVA PARAFULMINI S.r.l.

I guess exact function of the parts of the device can be found scanning in the related patents assigned to this firm.

Comment: Aha! I think I see it there on the right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqmim.jpg from the products menu. There are copy/pasteable blurbs on [this page](http://www.ingelva.it/index.php?pid=108&lang=E&ncol=1) as well. Thanks!

Comment: photo: http://www.ingelva.it/index.php?pid=103&lang=E&ncol=1 This is great!

Comment: Typo: Lighting != Lightning!

Comment: And given some of the keywords on that page like "electrosmog", it's probably a safe assumption that this equipment does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @duskwuff oh I hope not. I'd recently spent a small fortune on an anti-electrosmog aluminum foil hat-liner. Say it ain't so!